# Is it possible to pass dynamic values in default replacement of ZipAll in Scala?

Tags: scala

I was using `zipAll` for two unequal sized Lists, as shown below:

```scala
val prices = List(5, 10, 15, 20)
val fruits = List("Guava", "Banana", "Papaya", "Apple", "Mango")
```

I am using `zipAll` as shown below:

```scala
fruits zipAll (prices, "Undefined Fruit", "Price Unavailable")
```

Which yields following result:

```
List((Guava,5), (Banana,10), (Papaya,15), (Apple,20), (Mango,Price Unavailable))
```

What I am interested in is passing dynamic default fillers; so in this case, I am expecting something like:

```scala
fruits zipAll (prices, "Undefined Fruit", s"Price Unavailable for $fruitName")
```

Which should yield:

```scala
List((Guava,5), (Banana,10), (Papaya,15), (Apple,20), (Mango,Price Unavailable for Mango))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the stdlib doesn't provide such functionality, you need to implement it yourself like this:

```scala
def zipAllDynamic[A, B](left: List[A], right: List[B])(leftDefault: B => A, rightDefault: A => B): List[(A, B)] =
  left
    .map(l => Option(l))
    .zipAll(right.map(r => Option(r)), None, None)
    .collect {
      case (Some(l), Some(r)) => (l, r)
      case (Some(l), None) => (l, rightDefault(l))
      case (None, Some(r)) => (leftDefault(r), r) 
    }
```

Although, this is very expensive.
You may increase the efficiency of the operation using a tail-recursive function; or you can just use the magic of lazynes:

```scala
def zipAllDynamic[A, B](left: List[A], right: List[B])(leftDefault: B => A, rightDefault: A => B): List[(A, B)] =
  left
    .iterator.map(l => Option(l))
    .zipAll(right.iterator.map(r => Option(r)), None, None)
    .collect {
      case (Some(l), Some(r)) => (l, r)
      case (Some(l), None) => (l, rightDefault(l))
      case (None, Some(r)) => (leftDefault(r), r) 
    }.toList
```

Then you can use it like this:

```scala
val prices = List(5, 10, 15, 20)
val fruits = List("Guava", "Banana", "Papaya", "Apple", "Mango")

val result = zipAllDynamic(fruits, prices.map(_.toString))(_ => "Undefined Fruit", fruitName => s"Price Unavailable for ${fruitName}")
// result: List[(String, String)] = List((Guava,5), (Banana,10), (Papaya,15), (Apple,20), (Mango,Price Unavailable for Mango))
```

> **Note:** Remember **Scala** is a statically and strongly typed language, as such mixing `Int` and `String` as yu wanted would have resulted in a `List[(String, Any)]` which you never want, rather I converted all the prices to `Strings` before the zip.

*(How to convert this auxiliary function to an extension method is left as an exercise to the reader)*

---

You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/Xx90aqk8RkSKxM9g7VdfbA).

---

PS: If you use **cats** you can rather use `align` and the `map` to have better control over everything.

```scala
import cats.data.Ior
import cats.syntax.all._

val result = (prices align fruits).map {
  case Ior.Both(price, fruit) => s"${fruit} price is: ${price}"
  case Ior.Right(fruit) => s"Price Unavailable for ${fruit}"
  case Ior.Left(_) => "Undefined Fruit"
}
// result: List[String] = List("Guava price is: 5", "Banana price is: 10", "Papaya price is: 15", "Apple price is: 20", "Price Unavailable for Mango")
```

Thanks to Jasper to point out we can combine the previous `align` + `map` with just:

```scala
val result = prices.alignWith(fruits) {
  case Ior.Both(price, fruit) => s"${fruit} price is: ${price}"
  case Ior.Right(fruit) => s"Price Unavailable for ${fruit}"
  case Ior.Left(_) => "Undefined Fruit"
}
```

Comment: You can shorten to `alignWith`.

Comment: @Jasper-M I really need to do a meme about **cats** using the Shrek template like: _"Can you stop making my code more concise for FIVE MINUTES"_ :D